# What actually sets the input focus upon a window?

Tags: c, glfw

I understand that `focused` being true is set by default via the default window attributes, and I understand how it is checked for and how it might be manipulated via `GL_FOCUSED`, etc. If without manipulation, though, how does/can the input focus fluctuate between true or false, between windows, without the knowledge of the developer/user (if at all a possibility)? E.G. do certain functions (or any other component of the library) not centered on `GL_FOCUSED` draw the focus to/from certain windows (just as an example), and how might that be determined? General education purposes. I appreciate it. Have a lovely evening.

Answer (score 1):

In GLFW 3.2, `glfwFocusWindow()` is the only method that *explicitely* changes a windows input focus.

### but,

on some platforms such as Windows 7, *minimizing/iconifying a window gives the input focus to the last focused window.* That can either happen due to the user minimizing the window, *or* through the use of `glfwIconifyWindow()`.

### Other functions that may change input focus:

- `glfwIconifyWindow()`
- `glfwHideWindow()`
- `glfwDestroyWindow()`
- `glfwSetWindowMonitor()`


  Of course wether calling any of these methods *actually* change the input focus is pretty much solely dependent on the *underlying windowing system*, so an accurate list is pretty much impossible to compile, nevermind that it would be pretty pointless.